# Проверить по событию click зажат CTRL или нет

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, клавиатура

Есть элемент при клике по которому если ctrl зажат должно выполняться действие

сама идея состоит в том чтобы реализовать тот же принцип что и при выборе папок с зажатым ctrl то есть пока он зажат цвет будет меняться у всех элементов по которым кликнули, иначе только у текущего.

читал про события клавиатуры но они относятся именно к клавиатуре а у меня срабатывает событие мыши во время которого и нужно выполнить проверку зажата ли клавиша.

```js
$('.el').click(function() {
  ctrl = .....
  if(ctrl) {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
  } else {
    $(this).css('background', '');
  }
})
```

```css
.el {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #3F51B5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Информация о том, нажата ли клавиша <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> или нет, есть в [объекте события](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```
$('.el').on('click', function (event) { 
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
      // клавиша `Ctrl` нажата
  }
})
```