# "улучшение" input range

Tags: jquery

Сделал `<input type="range" value="0" min="-50" max="50" step="1"/>`
Хотелось бы его модернизировать добавив пару интересных плюшек:
1. Если щёлкнуть по инпуту с зажатым **ctrl**, то значение `value` изменится на 0;
2. Если двигать ползунок с зажатым **shift**'ом, то значение `step` изменится на 10;
Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. С первым пунктом легко. Недавно [решали такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/689899/196740).

   ```
   $(range).on('click', function(event) {
     if (event.ctrlKey) {
       $(this).val(0);
     }
   })
   ```
2. Со вторым сложнее. Идея следующая, отлавливаем событие перемещения указателя `mousemove`. В обработчике проверяем нажата ли левая кнопка мыши и нажата ли клавиша <kbd>Shift</kbd>, если условия соблюдены, устанавливаем значение `step` равное `10`

   ```
   $(range).on('mousemove', function(event) {
     // Проверяем зажата ли левая кнопка мыши http://api.jquery.com/event.which/
     if (event.which === 1) {
       $(this).prop('step', event.shiftKey ? 10 : 1);
     }
   })
   ```

   Так же нужно обработать события нажатия стрелок:

   ```
   $(range).on('keydown', function(event) {
     // Проверяем нажаты ли клавиши Left, Up, Right, Down
     if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) !== -1) {
       $(this).prop('step', event.shiftKey ? 10 : 1);
     }
   });
   ```

---

Полный код примера

```js
var range = $('input[type=range]');

$(range).on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    $(this).val(0);
  }
})

$(range).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 1) {
    $(this).prop('step', event.shiftKey ? 10 : 1);
  }
})

$(range).on('keydown', function(event) {
  // клавиши left, up, right, down
  if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) !== -1) {
    $(this).prop('step', event.shiftKey ? 10 : 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-50" max="50" step="1" />
```

Comment: Ох, это то что нужно. Спасибо!